# Swift: minify XML

Tags: swift, xml, string

This is not an advanced case, but I guess that could be useful for someone.
I was looking for a way to trim a multiline string from tabs and spaces.

In my case, I had an XML with complex set of tabs and NewLines like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RootNode attribute1="1.0" attribute2="client" attribute3="apiKey">
    <Node>
        <SubNode>
            <Value1>company</Value1>
            <Value2>userName</Value2>
            <Value3>password</Value3>
        </SubNode>
    </Node>
    <OtherNode attribute="datatype" attribute="method"/>
</RootNode>
```

I've tried to minify it: reduce newline symbols and whitespaces before each line.

#### Edited:

As mentioned in comments - simply replace of spaces wasn't an option since I need to save spaces inside of the XML.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest code snippet I've found that solves my case is:

#### Swift4:

```
let minified = xmlString.components(separatedBy: .newlines).map{ $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)}.joined()
```

Comment: I am sure that is fine for your use-case, but you should be aware that, as a rule, the XML standard says white space should be preserved, at least inside element text content.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyP, that was my original problem since I can't simply remove spaces from XML. The only way I found is to split XML into independent strings and trim each of them.